# Cant import cv2 (Model B) Python 3.5

Tags: camera, opencv

Basically Im very new to linux systems and an, above average in python, I intended to make a program that detect hand gesture (high five , victory one,three etc) , I created my own test code that doeast work since then I trien different codes from many people they all are stopping at same point that is cant import cv2 , due to following:

```
from .cv2 import * ImportError: libQtTest.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

before `libQtTest` , it was showing `libatlas` , which i installed , then it asked for `libjasper`, which I installed , but now cant find `libQtTest`.

For now Im trying to remove this error on following code, but it does shows the same error in other codes too, Ive thrice updated my pi.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

#Open Camera object
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#Decrease frame size
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1000)
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600)

def nothing(x):
    pass

# Function to find angle between two vectors
def Angle(v1,v2):
 dot = np.dot(v1,v2)
 x_modulus = np.sqrt((v1*v1).sum())
 y_modulus = np.sqrt((v2*v2).sum())
 cos_angle = dot / x_modulus / y_modulus
 angle = np.degrees(np.arccos(cos_angle))
 return angle

# Function to find distance between two points in a list of lists
def FindDistance(A,B): 
 return np.sqrt(np.power((A[0][0]-B[0][0]),2) + np.power((A[0][1]-B[0][1]),2)) 


# Creating a window for HSV track bars
cv2.namedWindow('HSV_TrackBar')

# Starting with 100's to prevent error while masking
h,s,v = 100,100,100

# Creating track bar
cv2.createTrackbar('h', 'HSV_TrackBar',0,179,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('s', 'HSV_TrackBar',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('v', 'HSV_TrackBar',0,255,nothing)

while(1):

    #Measure execution time 
    start_time = time.time()

    #Capture frames from the camera
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    #Blur the image
    blur = cv2.blur(frame,(3,3))

    #Convert to HSV color space
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    #Create a binary image with where white will be skin colors and rest is black
    mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv,np.array([2,50,50]),np.array([15,255,255]))

    #Kernel matrices for morphological transformation    
    kernel_square = np.ones((11,11),np.uint8)
    kernel_ellipse= cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))

    #Perform morphological transformations to filter out the background noise
    #Dilation increase skin color area
    #Erosion increase skin color area
    dilation = cv2.dilate(mask2,kernel_ellipse,iterations = 1)
    erosion = cv2.erode(dilation,kernel_square,iterations = 1)    
    dilation2 = cv2.dilate(erosion,kernel_ellipse,iterations = 1)    
    filtered = cv2.medianBlur(dilation2,5)
    kernel_ellipse= cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(8,8))
    dilation2 = cv2.dilate(filtered,kernel_ellipse,iterations = 1)
    kernel_ellipse= cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
    dilation3 = cv2.dilate(filtered,kernel_ellipse,iterations = 1)
    median = cv2.medianBlur(dilation2,5)
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(median,127,255,0)

    #Find contours of the filtered frame
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)   

    #Draw Contours
    #cv2.drawContours(frame, cnt, -1, (122,122,0), 3)
    #cv2.imshow('Dilation',median)

    #Find Max contour area (Assume that hand is in the frame)
    max_area=100
    ci=0    
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        cnt=contours[i]
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if(area>max_area):
            max_area=area
            ci=i  

    #Largest area contour             
    cnts = contours[ci]

    #Find convex hull
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnts)

    #Find convex defects
    hull2 = cv2.convexHull(cnts,returnPoints = False)
    defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnts,hull2)

    #Get defect points and draw them in the original image
    FarDefect = []
    for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
        s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
        start = tuple(cnts[s][0])
        end = tuple(cnts[e][0])
        far = tuple(cnts[f][0])
        FarDefect.append(far)
        cv2.line(frame,start,end,[0,255,0],1)
        cv2.circle(frame,far,10,[100,255,255],3)

    #Find moments of the largest contour
    moments = cv2.moments(cnts)

    #Central mass of first order moments
    if moments['m00']!=0:
        cx = int(moments['m10']/moments['m00']) # cx = M10/M00
        cy = int(moments['m01']/moments['m00']) # cy = M01/M00
    centerMass=(cx,cy)    

    #Draw center mass
    cv2.circle(frame,centerMass,7,[100,0,255],2)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    cv2.putText(frame,'Center',tuple(centerMass),font,2,(255,255,255),2)     

    #Distance from each finger defect(finger webbing) to the center mass
    distanceBetweenDefectsToCenter = []
    for i in range(0,len(FarDefect)):
        x =  np.array(FarDefect[i])
        centerMass = np.array(centerMass)
        distance = np.sqrt(np.power(x[0]-centerMass[0],2)+np.power(x[1]-centerMass[1],2))
        distanceBetweenDefectsToCenter.append(distance)

    #Get an average of three shortest distances from finger webbing to center mass
    sortedDefectsDistances = sorted(distanceBetweenDefectsToCenter)
    AverageDefectDistance = np.mean(sortedDefectsDistances[0:2])

    #Get fingertip points from contour hull
    #If points are in proximity of 80 pixels, consider as a single point in the group
    finger = []
    for i in range(0,len(hull)-1):
        if (np.absolute(hull[i][0][0] - hull[i+1][0][0]) > 80) or ( np.absolute(hull[i][0][1] - hull[i+1][0][1]) > 80):
            if hull[i][0][1] <500 :
                finger.append(hull[i][0])

    #The fingertip points are 5 hull points with largest y coordinates  
    finger =  sorted(finger,key=lambda x: x[1])   
    fingers = finger[0:5]

    #Calculate distance of each finger tip to the center mass
    fingerDistance = []
    for i in range(0,len(fingers)):
        distance = np.sqrt(np.power(fingers[i][0]-centerMass[0],2)+np.power(fingers[i][1]-centerMass[0],2))
        fingerDistance.append(distance)

    #Finger is pointed/raised if the distance of between fingertip to the center mass is larger
    #than the distance of average finger webbing to center mass by 130 pixels
    result = 0
    for i in range(0,len(fingers)):
        if fingerDistance[i] > AverageDefectDistance+130:
            result = result +1

    #Print number of pointed fingers
    cv2.putText(frame,str(result),(100,100),font,2,(255,255,255),2)

    #show height raised fingers
    #cv2.putText(frame,'finger1',tuple(finger[0]),font,2,(255,255,255),2)
    #cv2.putText(frame,'finger2',tuple(finger[1]),font,2,(255,255,255),2)
    #cv2.putText(frame,'finger3',tuple(finger[2]),font,2,(255,255,255),2)
    #cv2.putText(frame,'finger4',tuple(finger[3]),font,2,(255,255,255),2)
    #cv2.putText(frame,'finger5',tuple(finger[4]),font,2,(255,255,255),2)
    #cv2.putText(frame,'finger6',tuple(finger[5]),font,2,(255,255,255),2)
    #cv2.putText(frame,'finger7',tuple(finger[6]),font,2,(255,255,255),2)
    #cv2.putText(frame,'finger8',tuple(finger[7]),font,2,(255,255,255),2)

    #Print bounding rectangle
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnts)
    img = cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.drawContours(frame,[hull],-1,(255,255,255),2)

    ##### Show final image ########
    cv2.imshow('Dilation',frame)
    ###############################

    #Print execution time
    #print time.time()-start_time

    #close the output video by pressing 'ESC'
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How did you install OpenCV? Was it in a virtualenv with "pip install opencv-python" by any chance?

Comment: Either way you *probably* want to install the qt4-default package which'll pull in all the qt4 development headers. The reason I'm interested in how you installed it, is I'm wondering if your installation came from piwheels (which I'm partially responsible for, and where we've been mulling over how to inform users of the additional dependencies sometimes required)

Comment: I tried to uninstall and then reinstall it, but now its asking for math     "from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libImath-2_2.so.12"

Comment: then I tried "sudo apt-get install openexr" , now its simply again asking for "libQtTest "